# Cucumber not identifying scenario without examples

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have a gherkin scenario similar to following:

```
Scenario Outline: Test some behaviour
    Given a set of preconditions
    When an event occurs
    Then my application has to behave in a particular manner
    And respond as expected
```

When I execute this scenario my report says

> 0 Scenarios, 0 steps executed.

How ever when I execute a scenario with Examples, my setup works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: U are using a 'Scenario Outline' so u need to provide the examples table. Change  'Scenario Outline' to  'Scenario' if u want to run it once.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for the answer mate :)

Answer (score 6):

`Scenario Outline` is specific to `Examples`. If you swap to just `Scenario` you should be fine.